# MySQL update query in Wordpress plugin not working

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am developing a wordpress plugin but I am facing a problem. I would like to update an existing value of a table in a MySQL database. After some research, I saw that you can use this method:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE myTable SET name=$name WHERE id=$idTable"));
```

However when I run my code, I get this error in the javascript console:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null
```

Do you have an idea how to solve this problem ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your query. the $wpdb variable is null, therefore does not have a query() method. Make sure your $wpdb is a valid wordpress database object. Furthermore, pass variables as bound parameters to your prepared statements, otherwise there is no point using prepared statements.

Comment: The SQL also would be invalid, and open to SQL injections. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/ after you fix variable issue. `$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE myTable SET name=%s WHERE id=%s", array($name, $idTable)));`

Comment: I have modified my request and now do it like this: `$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE myTable SET name=%s WHERE id=%s", array($name, $idTable)));`. The mistake is always the same, what do I have to do concretely ?

Answer (score 0):

All you had to do was include the `wp-config.php` file with a `require`. Thanks anyway.